# Highlight current line only in line mode (not in char mode)

Tags: emacs

When working in ansi-term, how can I have emacs only highlight the current line when I am in `line mode`?  (and not in `char mode`?).

I currently have `(global-hl-line-mode t)` which activates `hl-line-mode` in every buffer (which I want). I just want to specifically disable it in `char run mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you want in two steps. First, replace `(global-hl-line-mode t)` in your `.emacs` file with the following lines:

```lisp
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          '(lambda () (hl-line-mode (if (equal major-mode 'term-mode) 0 1))))
```

This basically does the same thing as making `hl-line-mode` a global minor mode, as it turns on `hl-line-mode` every time the major mode of a buffer changes. But it doesn't turn on `hl-line-mode` if the new major mode of a buffer is `term-mode`. This way, `hl-line-mode` is disabled by default for `ansi-term`.

However, you do want to turn it on when you're in `line-mode` (but not in `char run mode`). For that, add the following lines as well to your `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(defadvice term-line-mode (after enable-hl-line-in-term-line-mode)
  (hl-line-mode 1))

(defadvice term-char-mode (after disable-hl-line-in-term-char-mode)
  (hl-line-mode 0))
```

Depending on which version of Emacs you're using, you might experience an odd behavior in the minibuffer with the above code: either the full line or parts of the line might get highlighted every time you use the minibuffer. To fix that, also add the following line to your .emacs file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook '(lambda () (hl-line-mode 0)))
```

---

<sub>This approach gives you quite a bit of flexibility over when `hl-line-mode` should be turned on or off. For instance, if you wanted to have other major modes for which `hl-line-mode` should be turned off, you could replace the `(equal major-mode 'term-mode)` portion of the above code with:</sub>

```
(member major-mode '(term-mode other-mode1 other-mode2))
```

where `other-modeN` are the names of the major modes for which you want `hl-line-mode` to be disabled. Of course you're not limited to only two such names.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, this is doing exactly the opposite of what I want. Part of this may have been my fault. I have updated the OP to make it more clear now. I would like **highlighting** only in **line mode** and not in **char mode**. 

At the moment your code does the opposite (it turns it **on** in **char mode** and **off** in **line mode**).

Comment: @user815423426 Really? That's odd, I just copied and pasted the code from the answer to my own .emacs file again and it works as expected for me, e.g., it is turned *off* in char mode and *on* in line mode). I did a bit of editing after I posted the initial version, would you mind trying it again with the current version?

Comment: Working now. I was probably using part of an older version. It works like a charm, and it makes it a lot easier to work with terminals. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, It looks like somehow this highlights my text when I type in the `mini-buffer`. Was that supposed to happen?

Comment: Does it happen every time you use the minibuffer, e.g. if you type M-x something, or only in some specific situations?

Comment: When I restart Emacs and open a terminal (by default in `char mode`) is all fine, but when I switch to `line mode`, the highlighting of the mini-buffer starts, and it doesn't go away even if I  switch to `char mode` or I kill the terminal.

Comment: So, you're saying that once you go into line-mode and then type, say `C-s` to search for a word, the text after the search prompt gets highlighted?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27293/discussion-between-thomas-and-user815423426)

Comment: Wwould you mind explaining on why you used a `defadvice` and not a `hook`? Is it because there are no hooks for `term-char-mode` and `term-line-mode`?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. (Despite their names, these aren't really *modes* so you cannot use something like `after-change-major-mode-hook` either.)